# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=heap' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql

excuse me I want to ask, on my website there is an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type = heap' at line 1" I do not understand for this

Comment: Where is the full query ?

Comment: show the query which is causing this error

Comment: error in the query..post the query please

Comment: Why tag SQL Server? A different product, with a different SQL dialect.

Answer (score 2):

`type` keyword is removed in mysql 5.5,  use `engine` keyword instead.